# How to support Chat in multiple languages: one deployment multiple button ids?

Tags: community, liveagent, community-builder, omnichannel, chat

**Goal:**

We want to display the same chat deployment on all different language locales in a community page, and then dynamically set the chat deployment button id based on the language.

**Ideas:**

We know that you can add logic to specify a button id using the embedded_svc.snippetSettingsFile.directToButtonRouting setting--although this determination is based on the prechat information.
We have also seen the option to specify "Routing Order" on the Embedded Service Chat component in Community Builder--but there is not clear documentation on how this works.

**Question:**

Does anyone have experience supporting chat in multiple languages?  Is there a way to dynamically set the button id based on url language settings? Could you potentially do that in the directToButtonRouting or in the Routing Order Settings?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest to have a single deployment with multiple chat buttons (One for each language). Alternatively, you can ask for a country in the pre chat form and based on it, you can dynamically populate embedded_svc.snippetSettingsFile.directToButtonRouting with the button id of that country. (You can maintain a custom setting for button ids and corresponding country) . In either of the ways, you need to create multiple buttons.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for this response--I appreciate your idea to use directToButtonRouting.  We did try this but the problem here is that the initial button (that is attached to the embedded chat deployment) must be online in order to display a prechat form and initiate directToButtonRouting.  We also ran in to the issue of the language based button (the button you are redirecting to) being offline which then displays a message that there are no agents online.  There is no way to redirect to offline support after this point, or else that may have been a viable solution.